# Google Speech API in Python

Tags: sockets, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio, grpc, google-speech-api

I am trying to build a system in python where audio is streamed from the client's browser via socket connections and then the audio is streamed to google cloud for speech recognition.

This is the code for the client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Audio Streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var app = {
            socket: null,
            mediaTrack: null,
            counter: 0,
            bufferSize: 4096,
            config: null,
            main: function(){
                this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000");
                this.socket.addEventListener("open",this.onSocketOpen.bind(this));
                this.socket.addEventListener("message",this.onSocketMessage.bind(this));
            },
            onSocketOpen: function(event) {
                this.initRecorder();
                console.log("Socket Open");
            },
            onSocketMessage: function(event){
                    console.log(event.data)
            },
            shimAudioContext: function(){
                try{
                    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
                    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || 
                        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                        navigator.msGetUserMedia;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert ("Your browser is not supported");
                    return false;
                }
                if(!navigator.getUserMedia || !window.AudioContext){
                    alert("Your browser is not supported");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            },
            initRecorder: function(){
                if(!this.shimAudioContext){
                    return;
                }

                return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ "audio": true,"video": false}).then((stream) => {

                    var context = new window.AudioContext();
                    //send metadata on audio stream to backend
                    this.sendContext(context.sampleRate);

                    // Caputure mic audio data into a stream
                    var audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                    // only record mono audio w/a buffer of 2048 bits per function call
                    var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(this.bufferSize, 1, 1);
                    // specify the processing function
                    recorder.onaudioprocess = this.audioProcess.bind(this);
                    // connect stream to our recorder
                    audioInput.connect(recorder);
                    // connect recorder to previous destination
                    recorder.connect(context.destination);
                    // store media track
                    this.mediaTrack = stream.getTracks()[0];
                    });
            },
            float32To16BitPCM: function(float32Arr) {
                var pcm16bit = new Int16Array(float32Arr.length);
                for(var i = 0; i < float32Arr.length; ++i) {
                // force number in [-1,1]
                var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, float32Arr[i]));
                /**
                * convert 32 bit float to 16 bit int pcm audio
                * 0x8000 = minimum int16 value, 0x7fff = maximum int16 value
                */
                pcm16bit[i] = s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF;
                }
                return pcm16bit;
            },
            audioProcess: function(event) {
                // only 1 channel as specified above.....
                var float32Audio = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0) || new Flaot32Array(this.bufferSize);
                var pcm16Audio = this.float32To16BitPCM(float32Audio);
                this.socket.send(pcm16Audio.buffer);
            },
            sendContext: function(rate){
                this.config = {
                    rate : rate,
                    language : "en-US",
                    format : "Linear 16"
                }
                this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(this.config));
            }
        }

        // app.main()

    </script>

    <input type="button" value="On" onClick=app.main()>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the audio in bytecode.

Now in my python code, I don't know how to stream it to the Google Cloud for voice recognition. Here is my python code:

```
import asyncio
import json
import io
import websockets
import threading
import queue



@asyncio.coroutine
def audioin(websocket,path):

    config = yield from websocket.recv()
    if not isinstance(config,str):
        print("Error, no conifg")
        yield from websocket.send(
            json.dumps({
                "error":"configuration not received as first message"
            })
        )

    config = json.loads(config)


    while True:
        data = yield from websocket.recv()


start_server = websockets.serve(audioin, "127.0.0.1", 5000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

How do I stream the **data** received from the WebSocket to speech.SpeechClient().streaming_reconize()???

Comment: did you get this answered? I had a working prototype based on https://gist.github.com/cobookman/6459f0423d56527ad136999e57d181ea

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the example of streaming speech recognition in Python.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#speech-streaming-recognize-python

You will need to configure the `SpeechClient` first. Then you will need to pack your websocket audio data stream into ProtoBuf messages.